# Jquery dynamically generated submit button and fields

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I submit this form after replacing the original submit button with a jQuery generated submit button?

Form:

```
<form action="url" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form horizontal" id="reg">        
     <select name ="type" id="owner">
          <option...>
     </select>
     <div class="controls-actions">
         <button  type="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

There is an event listener to add fields to the form:

```
$('#owner').change(function(){
    if($('#owner').val() == 1){
         $('#owner').after('<input name="added" value="2">');
     }     
})
```

Now, if I use the default submit button, the new field doesn't get posted, so I tried using `.submit()`:

```
//remove the old submit button and add new one
$('.control-actions').empty().append('<button id="added">Submit>');
```

Finally add an event listener to the newly generated button to submit the form:

```
$('#added').on('click', function(){
    $('#reg').submit(); 
})
```

Nothing happens when the newly generated button is clicked, no console errors, no form submission. I have also tried click(), delegate() etc.  jQuery version is 1.10

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do before you started removing and adding buttons? Because it sounds like you have [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/194720), and solving the original problem would be more beneficial.

Comment: @mike: Add dynamic fields to the form while keeping a submit button, that is, the form isn't submitted until it is clicked. A dynamic field could contain user input.

Comment: If that's your actual code, then `$('.control-actions')` isn't matching anything, because the class is "controls-actions."

Comment: Also, no reason to `.empty().append(...)` when you could simply `.html(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the form fields adding other field and substituting the submit button you can handle the newly created submit button with a delegated event.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#added', function(e) {
  //$('#reg').submit();
  console.log('#added clicked');
})


$('#owner').on('change', function(e){
    if ($('#owner').val() == 1){
        $('#owner').after('<input name="added" value="2">');
        $('.controls-actions').empty().append('<button type="button" id="added">Submit: click me to test</button>');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="url" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form horizontal" id="reg">
    <select name ="type" id="owner">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <div class="controls-actions">
        <button  type="submit" id="sub">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Typo in the question, will update. I've mixed the ids up.

Comment: @Kisaragi Right!  Try to use a delegated event. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $('.controls-actions').empty();
    $('<button id="added" value="Submit">').appendTo('.controls-actions').bind('click', function() {
         $('#reg').submit(); 
    });
```